# Replace default file of Ubuntu and Apache 2 on Google Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, server, apache2

Its my first time using the Google Cloud platform and I just created an Ubuntu server using Apache 2.

I don't know how to replace the default file located at: `/var/www/html/index.html` on the Google Cloud platform Ubuntu console. I have a file I want to replace it with on my Windows PC.

Comment: Either use the command line **gcloud compute scp** or use an SFTP GUI such as Bitvise. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance AND https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp AND https://www.bitvise.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te easiest way to transfer files from your computer towards a GCE instance is as follows:

1.- In the Cloud Console, go to the VM instances page.

2.- In the list of virtual machine instances, click SSH in the row of the instance that you want to connect to.

3.- After the connection is established, click the gear icon in the upper right of the SSH from the Browser window and select Upload file.

4.- The transfer dialog opens. Specify which file you want to transfer.

If you uploaded a file, the file is in your user's `/home/$USER` directory. You will just need to copy your file to the directory where the file your want to change is. For this you can run the following command:

```
sudo cp yourfile.html /var/www/html/index.html
```

You can also find some other ways to transfer data between your computer and the GCE instances following [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your question, please consider accepting it so other community members with similar issues can use this solution.